# What is this manga in which the King of Hell escapes Hell with his cat and becomes a high school student?

Tags: harlem-beat-wa-yoake-made

I think the storyline goes like this. The King of Hell escapes Hell with his cat. He assumes human bodies to start his new life as a high school student, while his cat becomes a beautiful nurse who works at the school. He is enjoying his new life with a goofy smile while people are trying to find him and bring him back to Hell. They can only recognise him by the extensive black ink tattoo on his back, which can be seen even in his human form. In his human form, he is short with whitish hair, and his cat is a beautiful black-haired beauty. However, in his demon form, he is very tall and handsome with black hair, and his cat returns to being a cat. I think it could have been yaoi-ish, but I can't remember though.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for [**Mad Love Chase**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Love_Chase) (Japanese title: *Harlem Beat wa Yoake made*).  That's one heck of a plot.

Synopsis from Wikipedia:

> A supernatural comedy about the Prince of Hell, Kaito, and his cat, Levun, who decide to run away together to escape an arranged marriage the Prince wants no part of. Somehow upon entering the human world, the Prince's appearances changes from tall, dark, and handsome to short, light and skinny, and his cat becomes a tall, busty female. Now the Prince is living life as a regular high school student and his cat is the school's nurse. Meanwhile, the King of Hell sends a womanizing vampire, a short tempered werewolf, and a kind hearted zombie to retrieve his son. Not to mention, the Prince's fiancée is not going to just wait around forever.

The main character also has the tattoo you had mentioned:

> He has a distinctive, black tattoo on the whole of his back, which identifies him as the Prince of Hell.

The original Tokyopop page cited there has a dead link for it's reference.

Comment: Any evidence on why you think this is what he/she is looking for?

Comment: Yes it is but its also called "*Harlem Beat wa Yoake made.*